# TensorFlow TFRecord with many images crashes during read

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm having trouble reading from a `TFRecord` file with "many" (more than ~500) events. If I create a file with 500 events, everything is fine, but more than 500 causes an error when I try to read and parse the file:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Invalid argument: Could not parse example input, value:
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 40: invalid start byte
```

The images are floats with shape `(N, 2, 127, 50)` (re-shaped to `(N, 127, 50, 2)` during the read). I've tried writing them two different ways: as a list of bytes and as a list of floats, and both fail in the same way.

For the "byte method", the business parts of the code are:

```
def write_to_tfrecord(data_dict, tfrecord_file):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file)
    features_dict = {}
    for k in data_dict.keys():
        features_dict[k] = tf.train.Feature(
            bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[data_dict[k]['byte_data']])
        )
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(feature=features_dict)
    )
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

and then reading:

```
def tfrecord_to_graph_ops_xtxutuvtv(filenames):
    def process_hitimes(inp, shape):
        hitimes = tf.decode_raw(inp, tf.float32)
        hitimes = tf.reshape(hitimes, shape)
        hitimes = tf.transpose(hitimes, [0, 2, 3, 1])
        return hitimes

    file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, name='file_queue')
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, tfrecord = reader.read(file_queue)

    tfrecord_features = tf.parse_single_example(
        tfrecord,
        features={
            'hitimes-x': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        },
        name='data'
    )
    hitimesx = proces_hitimes(
        tfrecord_features['hitimes-x'], [-1, 2, 127, 50]
    )
    return hitimesx
```

(Normally, I read and write other tensors also, but the problem is there with just one.)

For the "float method", the code looks like:

```
def write_to_tfrecord(data_dict, tfrecord_file):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file)
    features_dict = {}
    features_dict['hitimes-x'] = tf.train.Feature(
        float_list=tf.train.FloatList(
            value=data_dict['hitimes-x']['data'].flatten()
        )
    )
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(feature=features_dict)
    )
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

and, when reading:

```
def tfrecord_to_graph_ops_xtxutuvtv(filenames):
    def process_hitimes(inp, shape):
        hitimes = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(inp)
        hitimes = tf.reshape(hitimes, shape)
        hitimes = tf.transpose(hitimes, [0, 2, 3, 1])
        return hitimes

    file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, name='file_queue')
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, tfrecord = reader.read(file_queue)

    tfrecord_features = tf.parse_single_example(
        tfrecord,
        features={
            'hitimes-x': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        },
        name='data'
    )
    hitimesx = process_hitimes(
        tfrecord_features['hitimes-x'], [-1, 2, 127, 50]
    )
    return hitimesx
```

The data being written are NumPy ndarrays of type float32.

I'm tempted to think this is a bug (I'm using TensorFlow 1.0) because both methods work well for up to ~500 images, but break when I try to use more images. I've looked through the documentation to see if there are arguments I should add so the readers and writers can handle larger files, but I didn't find anything (and besides, 500 images is not a lot - I need to write 10's of millions of them).

Any ideas? I plan on trying with TensorFlow 1.2 today, but haven't had a chance yet.

Comment: I highly doubt it has something to do with the number of events. I am working with tfrecord files, each of them having 10mln events and everything is fine. I would suggest you to take one image and save it 1k times to see that it has nothing to do with the number 500. After that find which image breaks your reader and see how is it different from what you already have.

Comment: It wasn't event 500 - I tried that. I think it was a bug in TF 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to TF 1.2.1 and the above problem vanished (at least when using the `ByteList`s - I'm not sure which approach is more idiomatic TensorFlow, but treating everything as a `ByteList` and byte data is simpler code for me here).

There is a *new* problem which I believe occurs when *reading* a large file (now, I can write over 25k events, maybe more, in a TF record file) - namely that TF opens the whole file at once and loads it all into memory, and this is more than my test machine for data handling can deal with, but I don't blame this on TensorFlow directly (although I need to come up with some sort of convenient compression or chunking scheme, etc.).